# membership provider with social login feature

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm using custom `nhibernate` `asp.net membership provider` and now I want to allow social login feature (login with fb, twitter, linkedin). I know that already exists in simple membership provider outofbox but I need to support other databases than `microsoft sql server`, also I'm using code first principle  which means that I will generating db tables on the fly.

I'm looking for solution to extend my current user object (with extend properties to support social net. login).

THanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a common scenario, authentication with social websites has nothing to do with the way you store the data locally. Most providers support the oauth2 protocol which gives you back the username.

This means that if you store your accounts locally together with non-empty emails (which are somehow authorized), upon authentication the external site returns the information containing an email you can use to find a user in your local store.

On the other hand, using a local provider which uses some other database engine is completely unrelated to authentication with external providers. One of reasons people avoid answering your question is probably then that you have mixed two different and unrelated issues in one question.